# New Dell Latitude 7480 (2017): Trackpoint (pointing stick), 32 GB RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu, dell-latitude

I have noticed quite recently that Dell made this machine available: [New Latitude 7480](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-14-7480-laptop/pd?ref=PD_Family), however I'm struggling to find out whether:

1. is it possible to buy this model with keyboard with track point (pointing stick) - there are various photos, once with, once without track point (see image on "Operating System" paragraph)
2. is it possible to put into this beast 32 GB RAM? Processor should allow it ([Intel® Core™ i7-7600U](https://ark.intel.com/products/97466/Intel-Core-i7-7600U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz)), but who knows whether there's any other vendor limitation

Has anyone bought this machine or saw it somewhere? Any help appreciated, already tried to contact Dell directly but no luck with getting any answer.

I was checking `en-us` and `cz` Dell sites. `cz` site does not even list Latitude brand.

---

PS: Yes, this is follow up of my post ~year ago: [14" Notebook with 32GB RAM, track point ...](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2491/14-notebook-32gb-ram-ddr4-trackpoint-and-matte-display) - I'm still desperate.

Original thread at [hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/new-dell-latitude-7480-2017-trackpoint-pointing-stick-32-gb-ram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Thre are indeed two varieties for the keyboard on this model, one does have a pointing stick and one which does not (as the [Quick Start Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_latitude_laptop/latitude-14-7480-laptop_setup%20guide2_en-us.pdf) also shows "Pointstick (optional)"). It seems that only the [single least expensive](http://configure.us.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=cto01l748014us&model_id=latitude-14-7480-laptop&c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04) configuration misses it, and you can't choose to change it, you just need to take one of the more expensive configurations.

   To make sure yours has the pointing device look for "**Dual Pointing**" (as opposed to "Single Pointing" which the cheapest configuration lists) in the "The following options are default selections included with your order" section at the bottom of the configuration page.

---

2. As for RAM, the Owner's Manual (to be found [here](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/latitude-14-7480-laptop/Latitude_7480_OwnersManual/Memory-specifications?guid=GUID-3195AA9D-68C1-43FC-A8F4-3615EBF03A80&lang=en-us)) clearly
   states **Maximum memory 32 GB**

   (Though you'll have to buy all RAM anew because the even the 16GB
   RAM configuration comes with 2x8GB modules.)